# There seems to be so many robotic arms on the market, where can I get a list of pros/cons of each?

Tags: robotic-arm

Doing some research on robotic arms and thinking about getting one, but I was wondering where can I get info on the pros/cons of each one and how they compare to each other. Another important factor is which one has the largest community following.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which arms you are referring to?!

Answer (score 2):

There's no such list because if a property is an advantage or disadvantage depends on the application to a large degree.

This holds true for a lot of things in engineering and life in general.

You said nothing about your application. From your statement:

> thinking about getting one

it looks like you don't really have one either.

So what would you want to do with such a list anyway? Are you worried about making a mistake and buying the wrong arm? What if arm A has 20% more maximum force than arm B, but B has a 20% larger community? Would you want to come up with some weighted scoring system? How would you be able to decide which arm is right for you given that you have no experience with them and no clear requirements?

Just get started with any arm. This is the best way to gain experience with what matters and what does not.

Comment: I have a retail display window and wanted to build a robotic arm vending machine where users can pay via a bill acceptor and then the arm would drop the items to an opening.

Comment: Required speed? Weight of the objects? Safety considerations? Working volume of the robot? Budget? Normal items or cooled environment?